# How to pass thymeleaf variable from id created from thymeleaf object into javascript

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

I have an thymeleaf object - based on it's ID I'm creating ID's of my html elements. I need to take one of those ID's and place it into piece of javaScript so that I can pass value from one element to another...

For time being I've working javascript code but only on "solid" values. If I try to place thymeleaf variable it does not work. I assume it is connected with need of placing quotation marks around variable when I'm trying to select element by ID but I'm not sure...I tried to copy some code examples like below (sorry, stack don't have correct formatting and my html dissapears from editor when I paste HTML so I had to comment everything...):

```
  <!--<div id="editor" onblur="assignDivValueToTextArea()"-->

                                                  <!-- contenteditable="true">-->
                                                <!--Enter text here...-->
                                            <!--</div>-->

                                            <!--<textarea -->
                                            <!--th:form="${myth.getId()} + 'a'" th:id="${myth.getId()} + 777" name="content"-->
                                            <!--th:field="*{content}"></textarea>-->

                                            <!--<script th:inline="javascript">-->
                                                <!--function assignDivValueToTextArea() {-->
                                                    <!--var textAreaId = [[${myth.getId()+777}]];-->

                                                    <!--$("#" + textAreaId).val($("#editor").html())-->
                                                <!--}-->
                                            <!--</script>-->
```

For now I see my var textAreaId has the desided value (for example 'asd777') but for unknown reasons function does not recognize this string as an element ID. Strange as I have similar functions in other places of the HTML template (of course with another addons eg 'asd111') for modals (show/hide) and they work fine. Can someone advice me where is my mistake?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce, it seems it works as expected. If `textAreaId` and `id` attribute of `<textarea>` are equals I see no reason why this doesn't work. Anything happens when you edit that `div`?

Comment: Hi Jakub! thanks for analysis! Unfortunately issue still exists...Now I ran the code and with var textAreaId = [[${myth.getId()+777}]]; it does not work despite when I look it up in browser, it turns into '5c55bfeb80c30f1c9029353a777'  so the correct value...when I place only hard-coded var textAreaId =  '5c55bfeb80c30f1c9029353a777' into JS, then it runs corectly...